# Content Organizer does not work on a certain site

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule

We use the content organizer function to archive files in SharePoint 2019. The same rule is valid on other sites, but it doesn’t work on one of the sites.

Does SharePoint block some keywords?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The only difference I can find is the url.

[image]

[image]

Only files uploaded using code will have this problem. The corresponding timer job has also been set to be executed every 15 minutes.